# Pre-compiled Closure Templates - "Variable referenced before declaration" Warning in Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-templates

```
java -jar SoyToJsSrcCompiler.jar --shouldGenerateJsdoc --outputPathFormat 
           simple.js --srcs simple.soy
```

SoyToJsSrcCompiler generates a js file which looks like this:

```
if (typeof templates == 'undefined') { var templates = {}; }
if (typeof templates.simple == 'undefined') { templates.simple = {}; }

/**
 * @param {Object.<string, *>=} opt_data
 * @param {(null|undefined)=} opt_ignored
 * @return {string}
 * @notypecheck
 */

 templates.simple.tinyButton = function(opt_data, opt_ignored) {
     .....
 };
```

I am using Closure Compiler with `--warning_level=VERBOSE` and  `--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`

and I am getting this warning:

```
simple.js:1: WARNING - Variable referenced before declaration: templates
if (typeof templates == 'undefined') { var templates = {}; }
```

How can I clear this warning?

Comment: Try: `var templates=templates||{};templates.simple=templates.simple||{};`

Comment: @elclanrs This code is generated by SoyToJsSrcCompiler. I would have to edit it every single time the templates change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround is to declare the variables in an externs file with:

```
/** @suppress {duplicate} */
var template;
```

But the Soy compiler should be fixed.  I expect people don't see this because you typically use it with Closure Library and in that mode the Soy compiler should be generating:

```
goog.provide('template.simple')
```

Comment: You should also be able to include this definition in your sources as long as it is listed prior to the template sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Closure compiler with Soy, you should pass either `--shouldProvideRequireJsFunctions` or `--shouldProvideRequireJsFunctions`. Otherwise it assumes you are not going to use a compiler and generates code that browsers understand but is otherwise kind of iffy.

(Source: I help maintain the Soy compiler. We generally never test them compiler without either of those flags passed. It might make sense to make at least one of those flags mandatory because it really doesn't work well without them.)

Comment: Did you mean: " ... either `--shouldProvideRequireJsFunctions` or `--shouldProvideRequireSoyNamespaces` ... " ?